# how to secure the plain credentials used in k8s pull secrets

Tags: authentication, encoding, kubernetes, credentials, kubernetes-secrets

We are seeing the plain credentials as part of k8s pull secrets file. Is there any way to safely secure them so that admin/user who have full rights cannot misuse them?

Pull-Secret Example:

```
.dockercfg: 
   {"dockercentral.test.com:5050":
      {"username": "test.it.com",
       "password":"dwew32",
       "email":"mark.test@yahoo.com",
       "auth":"br23231fsdfdfsdfs3211"
      }
   }
```

Above is the Pull-secrets file, where we see the user name and password values as plain text. Please help on safely securing them in k8s!

Comment: All Secrets are merely base64-ed within kubernetes, but are you trying to defend against someone with `cluster-admin` gaining access to your secrets in the cluster? What is the threat model you are trying to defend against here?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel does it need `cluster-admin` though? Doesn't every kubelet have access to everything as well. So taking over _any_ node leaks all the secrets.

Comment: Yes, kubelet necessarily needs access in order to create containers. As for the Node, if you are allowing people to gain `root` access to your Nodes, they will have access to all the bind mounts and docker environment variables therein. Perhaps a system like [vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault#readme) has security guarantees you would like better? As several people have asked, what is the treat model you are trying to defend against?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I'm not the OP. I just pointed out that your example is a bit extreme (as there are some other significantly less powerful roles with much more realistic vector attacks) and one does not need to be `cluster-admin` to gain access to kubernetes secrets.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#registry-secret-existing-credentials) guide from kubernetes documentation to create secret of `docker-registry` type to authenticate with a container registry.

Example of `docker-registry` secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
name: myregistrykey
namespace: awesomeapps
data:
.dockerconfigjson: UmVhbGx5IHJlYWxseSByZWVlZWVlZWVlZWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGx5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eSBsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbG9vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb25ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubmdnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2cgYXV0aCBrZXlzCg==
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

As You can see this kind of secret doesn't have plain text credentials.

However user with cluster-admin rights can still easily decode them.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew pointed out currently, the main question is what you are trying to protect:

- If you're trying to protect it inside the cluster, you can use [Kubernetes RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) and limit access of specific users to the secret containing those credentials - just create a `Role`/`ClusterRole` that denies the permissions to get secrets in a specific namespace (or all namespaces). Then, bind this role (using `RoleBinding`/`ClusterRoleBinding`) to the relevant users - see the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) for more details.
- If you're asking "how to store it securely", Secrets is the way to go (as Piotr pointed out). This raises the question "how to store the secret" - and I cover a few options in [this post](https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-secrets-in-git/).

Hope that answer your question :)